# PHP: Fetch query row into multiple objects

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I would like to return a list of objects from a query to the database, and my question is **what is the most efficient way to implement this process**
because **my purpose is to generalize the method and extend it in my projects**.
Desirable that the process is not too much coupled to the connection driver etc.

I use PHP 5.4, MySQL 5.0 and PDO as the connection driver.

I describe it as a simple Master-Detail example, but it could be for any múltiple relationship tables. So these are the classes for the objects, and the equivalent database tables.

```
class Category
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct($pID, $pName)
    {
        $this->id = $pID;
        $this->name = $pName;
    }
}

class Item
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $description;
    private $category;

    public function __construct($pID, $pName, $objCategory, $pDescripton="")
    {
        $this->id = $pID;
        $this->name = $pName;
        $this->category = $objCategory;
        $this->description = $pDescripton;
    }
}
```

**First is built the query (in another process), Trying it be as generic as possible:**

```
$sql = "SELECT 
    e1.id as t1_c1, e1.name as t1_c2,
    e2.id as t2_c1, e2.name as t2_c2, e2.description as t2_c3
FROM category e1, item e2 
WHERE 
    e2.categoryId = e1.id";
```

I want to get the result as a list of objects. Because finally, each project will consist of entities represented by objects.

**As my first proposed**, for achieve that, It iterates all result records obtained as associative arrays, creating its objects in each iteration:

```
// From here, I wonder what is better or more efficient to implement
$result = array();
try {
    $query = $linkDB->query($sql);
    //It is by using the 'fetch' method, but is possible to use fetchAll? or another more efficient way?
    while ( $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        // Object no.2
        $objCategory = new Category($row["t1_c1"], $row["t1_c2"]);
        // Object no.1, and finally which is added to the list.
        $objItem = new Item($row["t2_c1"], $row["t2_c2"], $objCategory, $row["t2_c3"]);
        $result[] = $objItem;
    } 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
return result;
// ...
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't `execute()` a query call. that's for `prepare()` calls only

Comment: `FETCH_ASSOC` needs to be `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: but if you're just creating objects anyway the best way is to just return them as objects rather than creating a class for each one. `$row = $query->fetchObject()`

Comment: OK (Edited). Thanks, I wrote the code too quickly.

Comment: Classes should be exist because they implemented other functions about the scene, and they are entities. I think, with fetchObject() I can't get the result as I described.

Comment: if you want to keep the classes, use fetchObject and then pass the name of the class and it wil instatiate it for you. have a look at the php manual for it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken with `getObject()` method I can create just an object per iteration. Otherwise, can you help showing how it would implement in my example? Thanks.